# Can't catch exceptions from my class library

Tags: c#, .net

I have made a class library in .NET 3.5. My goal is to use it in existing webservices made with .NET 2.0.

I have a lot of exception handling in the webservice project but if an exception occurs in my classlibrary my handlers doesn't catch them and the calling method just exits!

When in "white coat" environment (read visual studio - debugging) there is no problem. But in my production environment - BOOM!

Comment: A little more information would probably help.

Comment: Maybe the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014/why-is-net-exception-not-caught-by-try-catch-block ?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace and your try-catch statement that is failing to catch the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Application and System event logs on the production box.  You should see some errors there.  Do they help diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you've wrapped the offending code in a TRY-CATCH block, and in the VS debugger it catches the exception as it should, but in the wild, it does not appear to catch the exception? Is it possible that it is catching it, but it's just handling it and not letting you know as you expect it to?

What's in the CATCH block that would notify you that an exception has occurred - logging of some type?